# Can a variable length argument be the replacement of single dimention array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, compiler-construction, arguments

**case 1:**

```
Class Test{
    public static void m1(int[] x){
        /* some code here */
    }
}
```

**case 2 :**

```
Class Test{
    public static void m1(int... x){
        /* some code here */
    }
}
```

Now tell me if **case 2** is applicable or not? If so then please explain me from the compiler's point of view. Another question: can a single dimensional array be the replacement of single variable length argument?

Comment: What do you mean by: "case 2 is applicable or not?".

Answer (score 0):

In case 2 compiler writes the array code for you. You can read [this](http://boyns.blogspot.ru/2007/12/java-15-explained-varargs.html) article for a description of what happens when you add a variable length argument.

Usage of varargs as a single argument when you need to pass one or more parameters is discouraged unless there is real need for that, because this approach is error-prone and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an array and then passing that as a parameter to a function, you can use `varargs`. Although, if you want to pass multiple arrays to your parameter and manipulate them **separately**, you probably shouldn't use `varargs`.

As an answer to your question, both cases **are** applicable. Both an `array` and `varargs` would be treated the same in your function. It's really up to you to choose which one best fits your situation.

Answer (score 0):

From a compilers point of view:

- **case1:** The length of `x` is known at runtime. `x`is somewhere on the heap and a reference to `x` is put on stack, when `m1` is called.
- **case2:** The length of `x` is known at compile time, because the source code lists all int-parameters explicitely. Each int is put on the stack, when `m1` is called.

There's actually another case. You can call `m1` of **case2** with `m1(new int[] {3,4,5});` which leads to stack handling as in **case1**.